# User is not able to see records

Tags: administration

I have few users under one profile. Two users under that same profile are not able to see any records. Those two users don't have the option **New** to create New records.
OWD - private, same permission sets for all users under that profile and Same role for all users

There are no other permission sets assigned to the user all have same permission sets

The profile doesn't have any permission on object

How could those two users restrict to create new records and see others records?

Comment: Is there a permission set assigned to other users?

Comment: Creating/Reading records are controlled from profile whereas which records can be viewed are controlled from owd, both are different things and thus while they have viewing rights, they may not be able to create one. Check if you have the "create" permission for the respective object on profile/permission set?

Comment: @PranayJaiswal No other permission sets assigned to other users

Comment: @JayantDas No create or anyother permission on Profile, In this case other users also shold not create or see other reocrds right as OWD is private. Updated my question

Comment: So if I am getting your question correctly, you want Users in a profile to be able to view records but not able to create any records. And that your profile is already set up that way to not allow creation of records, and the OWD is set to private. Is this the correct understanding?

Comment: OWD and creation is different.  Only profiles and permission-set allows the creation of the record. It has to be one of them. OWD is record access.